# Kohana 3.3 - how to correctly move controller function to model

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

again I've got a question about Kohana and how I am supposed to use model functions.

I want to move parts of a controller function into a more appropriate model to be able to access this function from additional controllers. (From what I have read so far I conclude that calling the controller function from a different controller is considered bad architecture). 
My problem is that depending on several circumstances (i.e. model parameters) this controller function creates a log entry in a different database table and sends an email to some users.

How am I supposed to create this log entry and send the mails if main functionality resides inside the model? Should I instantiate the second model from within the first, call the log function and afterwards send the mails exactly how I did from my controller?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you may be better off creating a Library class.  This would just be a regular class created in the classes/libraries directory of your application.  Within the library your methods can perform logic and call models, and be accessible from any controller.

Comment: That sounds interesting. I will try it.
Am I right that for the future I should use library functions whenever I need the implementation in more than one controller and it is not only model related?

Comment: You can find more information on the internet when you search for "repository". This takes al the db logic away from your controllers and you can reuse the the methods on different controllers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that doesn't have 1 correct answer, unfortunately. A lot of it comes down to how you prefer to implement the MVC pattern.

At its base MVC uses: **Models**, **Views** and **Controllers**

**Models**
*These classes should represent entities in your database*

Example:

**Model_User** maps to an entity in your **Users** table

```
$user = new Model_User;
$user->first_name = 'Joe';
$user->last_name  = 'Smith';
$user->save();
```

**Views**
*These files store presentation data/templates (html usually/mostly)*

Example:

**index.tpl**

```
<h1>HELLO, WORLD!</h1>
<h2><?=$some_variable_from_controller?></h2>
```

**Controllers**
*These files handle incoming requests and process data to be injected into **views***

Example:

**Controller_Home** handles request to the home page

```
class Controller_Home extends Controller {

    public function action_index(){
       $view = View::factory('index');
       $view->render();
    }

}
```

Now that you get the basics it's time to understand a specific problem this limited structure promotes. Controllers get kind of fat and messy. This leads us to **libraries** or a **service oriented architecture**.

These libraries allow us to move large groups of logic into a portable service layer that can easily be used across all controllers, models and other libraries. They also break our code up into smaller more concise chunks that actually made sense.

Example:

In my controller instead of using a bunch of logic that logs a user in via facebook I can simply create a **Social_Login_Service** and use it as follows.

```
Social_Login_Service::facebook($user_email);
```

Now you would simply see that 1 clean line in your login controller instead of a whole messy slew of logic that will pile up in your controller until it melts your brain to looks at.

This is a very basic overview of a possible direction (and one that I prefer).

It is very useful to break up your sites into smaller components and if you're using Kohana, I recommend doing this with Modules (http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/modules) they're great.

I hope this little snippet helped.